# Oracle Web service Date Returns Null in Java Code but Not in SOAP UI

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a web service that as far as I know is implemented by Oracle. I need to get a date from this web service. The here is a part of code that is generated for web service client in NetBeans:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "LASTENABLED", action = "LASTENABLED")
@WebResult(name = "LASTENABLEDOutput", targetNamespace = "Something",partName = "parameters")
public LASTENABLEDOutput lastenabled(
    @WebParam(name = "SDATE-LASTENABLEDInput", targetNamespace = "Something", partName = "parameters")
    SDATELASTENABLEDInput parameters);
```

and this is the code for LASTENABLEDOutput:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"_return"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "LASTENABLEDOutput")
public class LASTENABLEDOutput {

@XmlElement(name = "RETURN", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar _return;

public XMLGregorianCalendar getRETURN() {
    return _return;
}

public void setRETURN(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    this._return = value;
}

}
```

And this is how I call this web service:

```
LASTENABLEDOutput output = webservice.lastenabled(input);
XMLGregorianCalendar xMLGregorianCalendar = output.getRETURN();
GregorianCalendar calendar = xMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

`webservice.lastenabled(input)` returns a `LASTENABLEDOutput` object but the value of `output.getRETURN()` in the code above is null. However, in soap UI, I tested the webservice and it returns a valid answer: 
request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="a Url" xmlns:pkg="a URL">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <pkg:SDATE-LASTENABLEDInput>
         <pkg:TELNO-VARCHAR2-IN>some phone number</pkg:TELNO-VARCHAR2-IN>
         <pkg:SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN>10</pkg:SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN>
         <pkg:ENABLE-BOOLEAN-IN>true</pkg:ENABLE-BOOLEAN-IN>
       </pkg:SDATE-LASTENABLEDInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="a URL">
 <soap:Body>
   <LASTENABLEDOutput xmlns="a URL">
     <RETURN>07-JUL-15</RETURN>
   </LASTENABLEDOutput>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It may be helpful to say that there are other methods in this web service with other return types that work correctly with the same way that I called this method. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `07-JUL-15` is not a valid format for your specified XML schema "date".

SUGGESTION:

If you're generating the return value yourself ... then output in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: PS: I have no idea why this question appeared at the top of the "unanswered" list .... THREE YEARS after it was asked :(  Oh well...